# How to separate a string into different data types in C++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, split, stream

I want to read the following text from a file:

```
B-011 B 2250.50 Boda Alejandra y Mauro  
C-002 C 8000 300 Conferencia IEEE
```

And then separate each line (each string) into different data types. But not every line has the same format. The first line I want to divided into a string (B-011), a char (B), a double (2550.50) and string (Boda Alejandra y Mauro). The second one into a string (C-002), a char (C), a double (8000), an int (300) and a string (IEEE).

The file continues in a similar fashion. I have tried with the following code, but I can't make the cycle distinguish between each line.

```
stringstream ss;
string line;
char tipo;
string cveServicio, descripcion;
double ctoxHora;
int maxCantidad;

while(getline(file, line)){
    ss<<line;
    if(ss >> cveServicio >> tipo >> ctoxHora >> descripcion){
        cout << cveServicio << " " << tipo << " " << ctoxHora << " " << descripcion << endl;
    } else {
        ss >> cveServicio >> tipo >> ctoxHora >> maxCantidad >> descripcion;
        cout << cveServicio << " " << tipo << " " << ctoxHora << " " << maxCantidad << " " << descripcion << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we know what format the data has? Is `B` and `C` a clue?

Comment: So basically the difference between lines is, 4th position could be extra `int` on one of them? You can read first three anyway `>> string >> char >> double` then `.peek()` to see if the next data is a digit, then decide where to read the rest. But this will fail if one of the strings is an address, for example `3 Someway Somewhere`